# Theoretical delay before first approval

Tags: tangle, dag, white-paper

I'm reading the [white-paper about the tangle](https://iota.org/IOTA_Whitepaper.pdf). In pages 8 to 10, the author is calculating the average time for first approval of a tip on a stationary tangle.

The first result is that under low load:

> The first approval happens on an average timescale of order λ <sup>−1</sup>

where λ is the rate of arrival of new transactions. This result is clear to me.

But I must be missing something (maybe obvious) when the author present the result for a tangle under heavy load (page 10):

> Let us now consider the high load regime, the case where L<sub>0</sub> is large.
>   As mentioned above, one may assume that the Poisson flows of approvals
>   to different tips are independent and have an approximate rate of
>   2λ/L<sub>0</sub>. Therefore, the expected time for a transaction to receive its
>   first approval is around L<sub>0</sub>/(2λ) ≈ 1.45h (1)

Where:

- L<sub>0</sub> is the number of tips (large under heavy load).
- h is the average hidden time of a transaction (a transaction is hidden during the execution of the pow)

I don't see from where comes this factor: 1.45

I looked into reference "[Sheldon M. Ross (2012) Introduction to Probability Models. 10th ed.](http://bayanbox.ir/view/7776870545953264619/introduction-to-probability-model-S.Ross-math-cs.blog.ir.pdf)" (page 312) to have better understanding of the Poisson Process, but it didn't help me to understand why we obtain this result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1/ln2  from equation (3) in page 8. (in [version 1.2](http://untangled.world/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/iota1_2.pdf) of the whitepaper)

Comment: my version of white paper is 1.2 dated August 22, 2017 whereas your version is 1.3. Please check the equation 3 in version 1.2.

Comment: thanks for clarification about the version of the white paper. Wording in this section are very different. I hope that after reading both, I will eventually understand more deeply the math. Here is the link to old versions : http://untangled.world/iota-whitepaper-tangle/

Comment: L0/(2λ) ≈ 1.45h in v1.2, L0/(2λ) should be ≈ h in v1.3. I think they forgot to update. BTW, any idea in v1.3 pg8, why the mean number of chosen tips is 2r/(r+λh) ? And why equal to 1? Thx in advance.

Comment: Just discovered in pg 8 of v1.3 near last paragraph: "the expected time for a transaction to be approved for the first time is approximately h+L0/2λ = 2h". But then in pg 10: "Therefore, the expected time for a transaction to receive its first approval is around L0/2λ ≈ 1:45h (1)". which then should be ≈ h. Thus, it is very confusing! I don't know which statement is correct?!

Comment: @instantlink: Why is it that "the Poisson flow of approvals to it has rate approximately 2λ/L0" ? This statement followed with "(Recall Proposition 5.3 of [11], which says that if we independently classify each event of a Poisson process according to a list of possible subtypes, then the processes of events of each subtype are independent Poisson processes.)" I have checked eqn 5.3 of [11], it only shows memoryless property of exponential random variable. How they derived the rate =  2λ/L0 ?

Answer (score 2):

r/(r+λh) is a mean value  ( < 1 )
r is tips before time [t-h]
r+λh is a slightly higher number adding all tips from time interval [t-h,t]

since the node does not know λh tips are no tips any more at time index t (assuming λh is always stationary value), we have a total probability of choosing a tip of r/(r+λh) ( < 1 )

Total mean number of chosen tips is then 2*r/(r+λh) - you always select 2 tips.
Why this is equal to 1 in a stationary regime I also do not fully understand. I assume that the r number of tips and the λh number of tips should be equal (half/half for instance) and then a new addition of one transaction would not change it by much at that very moment - so resulting in 1 quotient. 
Anyone can confirm this interpretation?

What remains unclear after comments issued in other posts:
Why is the time for 1st approval L0/(2λ) ≈ 1.45h (or lets say ≈ h as in version 1.3 of paper)?

Paper states that during a period of h a transaction cannot be approved.

> This is because, by our assumption, during the first h units of time a
>   transaction cannot be approved, and after that the Poisson flow of
>   approvals to it has rate approximately 2λ/L0.

So it should it total be the sum of h + L0/(2λ) ≈ 2h

I think white paper needs an update on this. Moreover the link to the equation L0/(2λ) ≈ 1.45h (1) is wrong in v1.3

Answer (score 1):

Expected increment of # of tips at time t is: 
1 - 2*r/(r+λh) .....eqn(1) 
where "1" refers to new tip created by the tx and "2*r/(r+λh)" refers to expected # of "erased" tips. 
If the two "erased" tips were already approved (usually for small L(t)), then "2*r/(r+λh)" = 0, thus eqn(1) becomes positive or increasing.
If the two "erased" tips were not previously approved (usually for large L(t)), then "2*r/(r+λh)" = 2, thus eqn(1) becomes negative or decreasing.
If one "erased" tip was already approved and one not previously approved (for L(t) becomes stationary or L0), then "2*r/(r+λh)" = 1, thus eqn(1) becomes zero, neither increasing nor decreasing. 
Thus L(t)=L0, eqn(1) = 0; 1-2*r/(r+λh) = 0; therefore 2*r/(r+λh) = 1.